# Controller not showing WSDL /w SoapServer in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, soap, wsdl

I am trying to migrate an old project from Symfony 2 to Symfony 4.3.
The old project used a package call [BeSimpleSoap](https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleSoap) in order to provide a SOAP endpoint. When I open the according endpoint in my browser, it shows me the XML.

Now in my Symfony 4 Route, I'd like to keep the exact same route. 
According to the docs, I created a SOAP endpoint like this:

```
$soapServer = new SoapServer($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir') . '/public/SmsV6.wsdl');
$soapServer->setObject($smsService);

$response = new Response();
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1');

ob_start();
$soapServer->handle();
$response->setContent(ob_get_clean());

return $response;
```

Unfortunately it shows an empty xml when calling `localhost/my-endpoint`. However, when calling `localhost/my-endpoint?wsdl` it gives me the correct XML. Since I cannot change the way the url is called, is there any way to send the `?wsdl` without having it in the url. What does that even do, can I provide it as an argument to the `SoapServer`?

*I tried*
`* @Route("/my-endpoint{wsdl}", name="soap", defaults={"wsdl"="?wsdl"})`
But that throws an `missing root element` error when calling the route...

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like a routing problem, and completely unrelated to the Soap client thing, right?

Comment: Maybe not completly as there may be an option to make the SoapServer display the wdsl by default and not only if the `?wsdl` is attached to the route. If there isn't then it may only be a routing problem...